# Shrinking file that is opened in read/write

Tags: perl, file-io, readwritelock

In perl:

I have a file opened in read/write, with an exclusive lock.

`open( $f, "+< $filename" );

flock( $f, LOCK_EX );`

If I write more data to the file than it previously held, the file will grow.
If I write less data, my new contents are at the beginning, but the old contents are still there at the end of the file.

This isn't surprising, however it's not what I want.

Is there a simple way to shrink the file while it is opened in read/write? Basically I want to tell it to end the file at exactly this byte position.

I know I can open it differently, and I'm considering doing that, but a one line fix would be nice.

Comment: I would suggest testing the result of the open, flock, truncate, etc.

Comment: @hpavc, or use [autodie](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie).

Comment: I am testing the results of all these commands. Just cut them out for brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`truncate`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html)

Comment: You both win a cookie. I can't accept your answers for 9 minutes though (Why is that?).

Comment: I even searched for the word truncate, and managed to miss that somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't know about perl, but since `ftruncate(2)` would be the C function, maybe [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html) helps?